# Reasons to use Server OS?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012

So I'm working on a paper about Windows Servers (specifically 2012 R2 but doubt anyone will understand most of its features anyway so trying to generalize it a bit), and I'm wondering about these things :

What is the drawbacks of using desktop OS on Servers ? And the reasons on why those drawbacks happen/exist? And probably a little background on why use Windows Servers instead..

Tried to google it but can't seem to find the answer.. most of them focuses on the features and reading it just made me lost even more

Comment: Feels too broad. Worth considering how MS differentiates their products - IIRC older desktop OSes had a limited number of open network connections, you can't host stuff like AD servers and so on. The number of sockets/cores supported, and maximum ram are different too. I'll probably leave it for the community or another mod to close, but the features are really why you should choose a server os over a client os for a server

Comment: hmmm.. let's talk about a data server for a home-based office just for data sharing to make life easier (less than 10 users or so), what would you say the features in Win Server that's going to be useful and doesn't exist on desktop OS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Desktop OS has limitations on number of users and network connections. If you plan to use for a 3-people family or a 3 people office, it probably makes little difference. If you use it in a serious multi-user environment, it will not work, as the n+1 th user cannot connect, etc.

There are many other small diffs, but that's probably the most important one.